# Enter in context menu posts comment

Tags: bug, comments

I tend to use the context menu key to correct typos. Context key, select word, enter. The normally I will press down to get to the end of the row. Enter in the context menu posts (with about a 0.5 second delay so it does it just as I press down!!). This one is real! Honest!

Can this be turned off?

Comment: daskfjdsjfkljkla;jdlfjsdakljfkldsj;lkfdfsdafsdajskdljfaafgalfdhjsdfds;lakjfkldsjfkljdskajf;dlskajfkldsjaklf dsafsdfdsasafsdafdsgfdsfdgsaagge Can't reproduce.

Comment: sdfasdfasdfasdf
asdfsd;fkjasdfkjasdfkjasd;fjkasd;4fkjsdfsdjfasdkfjas;ldkfjas;dklfjas;dfjas;kld4sdfjasdkl=;fjas;ldkfjas;ldjfa;klsd4sdfasdfasdfsdfasdfasdfasdfasdf Me either

Comment: km;kmlkmlmlk, hm, Is this a laptop? the keyboard might be broke and pressing the buttons at the same time.

Comment: Can you run `xev | grep key` then press the down button and the enter button, and copy the output into your question?

Comment: Here we go  

state 0x10, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 116 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,

WAIT IT IS NOT THE DOWN KEY! STUPID ME!!  SEE EDIT^^

Comment: I think you should try [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2061/disable-enter-for-submitting-comments).

Comment: Hmm there is some kind of bug in that script. It stops me even entering a comment. I click comment and it doesn't open the box. Instead is scrolls the page to the top. Still we are getting somewhere! I will play with the script later today when I am less busy. Thanks!

Comment: This is me testing the greasemonkey script. You should never see this as I will just hit enter in the context menu. - Doesn't work.. yet!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I am very bothered by it actually. Sometimes I want to correct a word with the builtin dictionary (or paste something, etc. whatever has to do with the contextual menu) and press enter then it sends my comment. Somehow I've learned to use more the mouse but it's a pain moving my hands from the beautiful and precious keyboard to grab a dirty <strike>rat</strike> mouse.

Comment: I'll work on the greasemonkey script later and see if we can have a work-around.